# Varying content of an SQL update statement in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-update

I need to write an update function where its content is different based on what parameters are passed, e.g. if I have `updateBook(int id, String title, String author, int pages)`, I have to do something like:

```
String sql;
if((!title.equals("null"))&&(!author.equals("null"))&&(pages>0)))
        sql = "UPDATE book SET title='"+title+"', author='"+author+"', pages="+pages;
else if(((!title.equals("null"))&&(!author.equals("null")))
        sql = "UPDATE book SET title='"+title+"', author='"+author+"'";
else if(((!title.equals("null"))&&(pages>0)))
        sql = "UPDATE book SET title='"+title+"', pages="+pages;
... //and so on

sql = sql + " WHERE bookid="+id+";";
```

The more fields I have in my table, the more checks I have to do, which is uncomfortable, and requires me to write a lot of code.
Also, doing something like:

```
sql = "UPDATE book SET ";
if(!title.equals("null"))
        sql = sql +"title='"+title+"',";
if(!author.equals("null"))
        sql = sql+"author='"+author+"',";
if(pages>0)
        sql = sql+"pages="+pages";
sql = sql + ";";
```

can't work since the unwanted commas cause statement errors.
You can see as well that if I have something like 6, 7, 8 etc field the checks start to get too many, and I can't also do more separated update statements as if something goes wrong I would need to rollback any query that has been done in that function.

Is there any way round to get a custom update statement having to write few code?

Comment: Consider using an ORM like Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).
I would do it something like the following.

```java
List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
if(!title.equals("null")) {
   sql.append("title = ?");
   params.add(title);
}
if(!author.equals("null")) {
    if (sql.length() > 0) {
        sql.append(", ");
    }
    sql.append("author = ?");
    params.add(author);
}
if(pages>0) {
    if (sql.length() > 0) {
        sql.append(", ");
    }
    sql.append("pages = ?");
    params.add(pages);
}
if (sql.length() > 0) {
    sql.insert(0, "UPDATE book SET ");
    sql.append(" WHERE bookid=?");
    java.sql.Connection conn = // however you obtain it
    java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
        ps.setObject(i + 1, params.get(i));
    }
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: This works, dunno why I didn't think of checking the string length. Thanks alot!